# Finding DNA sequences of length $3$

Tags: combinatorics

In the following question I am trying to determine how many DNA sequences of length $3$ that have no $C$'s at all or have no T's in the first position.

Below are my workings,

So there are $4$ DNA letters, $A,T,C,G$

**Considering how many DNA sequences of length $3$ that have no $C'$s,**

in the first position we have $3$ options, then in the next position we have another $3$ options to fill in, and then finally in the last position since its length $3$ we have $3$ options, therefore by the product rule we have,

$$3x3x3 = 3^3 = 27$$

**Considering DNA sequences of length $3$ that have no $T's$ in the first position**

in the first position we have $3$ options, then in the next position we have $4$ options to fill in, finally in the last position since its length $3$ we have $4$ options, therefore by the product rule,

$$3*4*4 = 3*4^2 = 48$$

So my questions are the following,

**1) Am I using the product rule correctly?

2) What does the or mean in this case? Is it two different questions or is it all one question and I will need to use the sum rule to combine both answers above?**

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct for each separate question -- you are using the product rule correctly.

If the question imposed both restrictions simultaneously, you should proceed much in the same manner as you did before: how many possibilities are there for the  first position? What about the second? And so on. There is no 'sum rule' at play here.

---

Assuming the 'or' in the question is the logical or, then you wish to find $|\mathcal A\cup \mathcal B|$, where $|\mathcal S|$ is the number of elements in the set $\mathcal S$, $\mathcal A$ is the set of length $3$ sequences with no $C$s, and $\mathcal B$ is the set of length $3$ sequence without $T$ in the first position.
By inclusion-exclusion, we have

$$|\mathcal A \cup \mathcal B|= |\mathcal A| + |\mathcal B| - |\mathcal A \cap \mathcal B|$$

You have already calculated $|\mathcal A|$ and $|\mathcal B|$ so it remains to compute $|\mathcal A \cap \mathcal B|$.
Now, $\mathcal A \cap \mathcal B$ is the set of length $3$ sequences without $C$s *and* without $T$ in the first position, ie, both conditions apply simultaneously.
Here we may apply the product rule as you did in your calculations to find that

$$|\mathcal A \cap \mathcal B| = 2\times 3 \times 3 = 18$$

Comment: okay so the or word makes it separate but if it was and instead of or I would use the sum rule?

Comment: What do you mean by 'sum rule'? I'm not sure I understand your question

Comment: Hopefully the new edit answers the question more thoroughly.

Comment: so I'm not answering two questions here I should be saying that for the first position I have 2 options since there is no C or T allowed, then the net position I have 3 options since there is no C allowed and finally the last position I have 3 options because there is no C allowed, therefore by the product rule $$2*3*3=2*3^2=2*9=18$$

Comment: Have you seen my edit?

Comment: I did just checking to see if my logic sounds right

Comment: What you just did (above, in the comments) is the calculation of $|\mathcal A \cap \mathcal B|$ in my edit. If I understood correctly, your question asks for the calculation of $|\mathcal A \cup \mathcal B|$.